# Firebasedata not populating tableView

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from Firebase, and write it in a `tableView` but the data is not populating the `tableView`
When I print the data inside the closure where I read the data, it prints correctly, but outside the closure it prints blank values. It also prints correctly inside `viewDidAppear`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserProfileTableViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    private var gotName: String = ""
    private var gotAdress: String = ""
    private var gotPhone: String = ""

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.gray

        //Get userinfo from database

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let userInfoRef = Database.database().reference().child("userprofiles/\(uid)")

        userInfoRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let name = value?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
            let address = value?["Address"] as? String ?? ""
            let phone = value?["Phone"] as? String ?? ""

            self.gotName = name
            self.gotAdress = address
            self.gotPhone = phone
          print("Print inside closure in viewDidLoad\(self.gotName, self.gotAdress, self.gotPhone)") //This prints the correct data
            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }



        let testRef = Database.database().reference().child("Test")
        testRef.setValue(gotName) // Sets value to ""

       print("Print inside outside in viewDidLoad\(self.gotName, self.gotAdress, self.gotPhone)") //This prints blank values
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("Print in viewDidAppear closure\(self.gotName, self.gotAdress, self.gotPhone)") //This prints the correct data
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserProfileCell") as! UserProfileCell

       cell.userProfileLabel.text = gotName


        return cell

    }
```

The print statement outside the closure where I read data in `viewDidLoad` is the first to be printed in the console if that matters?

Comment: That's a very common misunderstanding: `observeSingleEvent` work asynchronously. The print line at the end of `viewDidLoad` is pointless. Do the things you have to do in the completion handler where *the correct data* are printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting data from Firebase or from any server service is done in asynchronous way. That's why when you try to print variables outside closures it doesn't print anything. Try calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside closure and it will show your desired data.